# Is there a way to quickly change dir to one from where one of the jobs is running?

Tags: bash, cd-command, jobs

The output of `jobs` looks something like this

```
[1]   Stopped                 TERM=xterm-256color vim --servername vim ~/.gitconfig
[2]-  Stopped                 TERM=xterm-256color vim --servername vim ~/.vimrc  (wd: ~)
[3]+  Stopped                 TERM=xterm-256color vim --servername vim i3blocks.conf  (wd: ~/.config/i3/configs)
```

where the `(wd: path)` part, if present, shows the *`path`* of dir from where the corresponding job was started.

Several times I want to move to that dir for one of the jobs.

Is there a utility for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, the `$jobdirs` associative array maps  job numbers to the working directory they were started from, so you can do `cd $jobdirs[n]` to `cd` into job n's directory (or `cd ${jobdirs[n]?}` to get an error instead of taking you home if the job doesn't exist).

```
~$ jobs -d
[1]  - running    sleep 1000
(pwd : /tmp)
[2]  + suspended  sleep 123123
(pwd : /usr/local)
~$ cd $jobdirs[2]
/usr/local$
```

See also the `$jobstates` and `$jobtexts` associative array for the state and code of each job.

In `bash`, your only option is going to be parsing the  output of jobs which unfortunately can only be done with heuristics. For instance, see:

```
bash-5.1$ mkdir ') (wd: blah blah)
[5] (wd: blah blih)
'
bash-5.1$ cd ') (wd: blah blah)
[5] (wd: blah blih)
'
bash-5.1$ sh -c 'sleep inf' '(wd: /etc)
[2] (wd: bloh bloh)
'
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sh -c 'sleep inf' '(wd: /etc)
[2] (wd: bloh bloh)
'
bash-5.1$ jobs 1
[1]+  Stopped                 sh -c 'sleep inf' '(wd: /etc)
[2] (wd: bloh bloh)
'
bash-5.1$ cd /
bash-5.1$ jobs 1
[1]+  Stopped                 sh -c 'sleep inf' '(wd: /etc)
[2] (wd: bloh bloh)
'  (wd: ~/1/) (wd: blah blah)
[5] (wd: blah blih)
)
```

You can see that the `(wd:...)` is only printed if the job's dir is not the current working directory, and if the job's command line or working directory happens to contain `(wd: ...)`  there's no way to tell  which of the `(wd:`s is the start of the actual working directory.

Also replaces your home directory with `~`.

Also beware the `wd:` is localised. For instance, in Ukrainian:

```
bash-5.1$ LC_ALL=uk_UA.utf8 jobs 1
[1]+  Зупинено        sh -c 'sleep inf' '(wd: /etc)
[2] (wd: bloh bloh)
'  (РД: ~/1/) (wd: blah blah)
[5] (wd: blah blih)
)
```

So you would want to make sure `jobs` is called in the locale for which you expect the corresponding *working directory* abbreviation.

All you could do is use heuristics and hope for the best:

```
cdj() {
  local dir
  dir=$(LC_ALL=C jobs -- "$1") || return
  case $dir in
    (*'(wd:'*')')
      dir=${dir%')'}
      dir=${dir##*'(wd: '}
      case $dir in
        ('~'*) dir=$HOME${dir#'~'}
      esac
      printf >&2 '%s\n' "Job $1's dir is likely \"$dir\""
      cd -- "$dir";;
    (*)
      printf >&2 '%s\n' "Job $1's dir is likely the current directory already"
  esac
}
```

Which fails in our contrived example above but should work in most normal cases.

Comment: forgot to mention I'm in bash, sorry. I've just added the tag. +1 anyway.

Comment: (1) should `$dir` be quoted in a few places? (2) what is `local dir`?

Comment: @Enlico (1), all those unquoted parameter expansions or command substitutions are not in list contexts, so quoting in not necessary (though wouldn't harm). (2) `local dir` declares a `dir` variable that is local to the function. See `info bash local` for details.

Comment: about my *"wouldn't harm"* above, strictly speaking, in very old versions of bash (2.04 or earlier), `dir="${dir%')'}"` wouldn't work as the `'`s would be taken literally. `dir="${dir%)}"` would work in bash but not several other shells. `dir="${dir%\)}"` would be the most portable one. In any case, I don't expect you'll find that old versions of bash in this day and age. Omitting the outer quotes, which is fine here as it's a scalar assignment, so no split+glob can happen removes the question of what nesting those quotes should mean.

Comment: FWIW, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) suggests to `cd -- "$dir" || exit` or `cd -- "$dir" || return` instead of just `cd -- "$dir"`.

Comment: @Enlico, here, cdj is a cd wrapper. The user of cdj should do `cdj somedir || exit` if they were using that in a script, but here, it's about job control, so it hardly makes sense in a script. You can add a `|| return` to silence shellcheck but that won't make a difference since `cd` is the last command run in that function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've solved the problem definig the following function in my `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
cdj () {
  jobNumber="$1"
  dir="$(jobs | grep "^\[$jobNumber\]" | sed 's/.*(wd: \(.*\))/\1/;t;d')"
  [[ -n "$dir" ]] && eval "cd $dir"
}
```

so that I can do `cd job-number`, which (intentionally) fails if I pass the number of a non existing job or of the job running from the current dir.

Comment: That `eval "cd $dir"` would only work for `$dir` that don't contain any special character in the syntax of the shell and could have severe consequences if not (think of  a job started in a directory called `;rm -rf ~` for instance).